# Delete rows from A matching rows in B in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, sql-delete

I currently have a table with multiple duplicates across the primary key columns due to a lack of integrity checks. Be that as it may, I'm attempting to remove the duplicates. The problem is, there's no `id` column, which means that finding the duplicates is nontrivial.

My current solution involves using the `count(*)... having` construct to create a second table, and selecting the rows to be deleted into there. My problem is that the SAS `delete` command doesn't allow for the following:

```
proc sql;
delete from TableA
where (v1,v2,v3) in TableB
```

Is there any way to delete from one table based on the contents of another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
delete from TableA as a
where a.v1 = (select b.v1 from TableB as b where a.primaryKey = b.foreignKeyForTableA)
```

and so on for the other values. However, since you may recieve duplicates (ie more than one result) from TableB you might want to try out "select distinct" or "select Top 1" to only get one result.

Comment: in my case i had to use `where a.v1 in` instead of `where a.v1 =`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove every observation from your dataset where more than one observation has the same value of your "key" variables (removing ALL duplcates).

The best and easiest way to do that with SAS is to sort that dataset by your "key" variables and then use another data step to create your new copy.  Harder to explain than to illustrate:

```
data have;
   input x y z;
   datalines4;
1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 6
3 4 7
4 5 6
4 5 6
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=have;
   by x y z;
run;

data want;
   set have;
      by x y z;
   if  first.z and last.z;
run;
```

The sub-setting `IF` statement keeps only the four "unique" observations using the automatic `FIRST.` and `LAST.` variables created when you use a `BY` statement.

If instead you wanted to keep one of the duplicates, you could use the `NODUPKEY` option with `PROC SORT`:

```
proc sort nodupkey data=have out=want2;
   by x y z;
run;
```

This will eliminate two of the observations from the example, leaving you with unique values for your key.  You cannot control **which** observations are retained using this technique.

Comment: I do like the idea of using `nodupkey`, but the fact I can't control which ones are retained makes this approach problematic.

Comment: I found this to be a useful and general solution - Much simpler if you're already using SAS than doing the equivalent in SQL. If you want to control which duplicates get deleted, you could add a conditional before `if  first.z and last.z;` in the data statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
proc sql;
delete from TableA
    where exists (select 1
                  from TableB
                  where b.pk = TableA.v1 or b.pk = TableA.v2 or b.pk = TableA.v3
                 )
```

Comment: @eykanal . . . Yes, I had originally written it as an `in` statement, and then realized that `NULL` could cause problems.  I seemed to have left an extra open paren.

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you check the changes make by waka, they looked ok on first sight...but I'm no SQL expert...

Comment: @owlstead . . . I put my formatting back.  An extra paren was added at the end.

Comment: OK, but I presume the edit from `Table` to `TableB` was on the mark :)